# Internet Explorer cannot display drop down menu properly

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, navigationbar

When i run my project in IE8 my drop down menu in navigation bar seems not working properly as in Chrome and Firefox. Its appear in bullet forms that line in the left side of the page.See the image below.

[image]

This happen when i try to alter the URL of my existing website. I put all my php file inside folders and I  call them  using  `../../` method. I also implement this method to call the css file.

Here is the difference between the two code (code from existing website and code where i implement the `../../` method)

[image]

Here is my css file.
http://jsfiddle.net/9UHcb/
http://jsfiddle.net/bvTzu/
http://jsfiddle.net/frr8d/

please help me guys.

Comment: Hit F12 and look in the script console

Comment: Does your style sheet have any @include directives?

Comment: i also tried <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/> but still it didnt work

Comment: Is the problem with your existing website and IE, your new website and IE, or both?

Comment: @JAL happen to my new website and IE

Comment: share the staging url.

Comment: @MaheshBudeti , for my  original website, i can directly call my php file. For example, localhost/alarm.php. I wanted to change my existing URL to be more friendly, for example localhost/alarm-system/alarm.php so i create folders and put the php file inside. Here is my folder structure; alarm-system>>alarm.php. I use ../ method to call the header in the root.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using relative paths such as "../" use the absolute path.

Define a constant variable for absolute path in your configuration file as:

> define('ABSOLUTEPATH',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);

Now you can include the files as:

> include(ABSOLUTEPATH."/templates/filename.php");

if you don't have any config file something like below can be used:

> $root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
>
> include "$root/inc/include1.php";